# Disable password age policy for admin on Windows Server

Tags: password, windows-sbs-2008, group-policy, security

By default on my SBS08, the Maximum password age is set to 1year.
I'd like to disable this particular parameter for Domain Admin, not the entire policy (Default Domain Policy).

Is that possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a really bad idea... I'm guessing you're using the domain admin account for services (which you should be creating service accounts for), or just don't want to ever change the most important password in your whole network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how to do it: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770842(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Or for those that don't follow links, that's linking to the step-by-step guide to Fine Grained Password Policies in AD. It is EXACTLY how you set password policies domain-wide, and still exempt your admin/utility users. Beats the pants off of the old way.